# Screen recording while testing

Tags: windows, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am searching for a light weight screen recording tool I can use to record automated test runs in the background.

I have a detailed logging for my automated GUI application tests running on Windows 7 but sometimes I can not find out what happened when I return. Also some actions are to fast to exactly follow them.

This is why I would like to use a screen recorder. It should have the following features:
- For free if possible, maybe open source
- Frame exact screen recording, audio not necessary
- Windows 7 and XP compatible
- Light weight, should not influence the system load too much
- It should be possible to be started automatically (using command line or by adding some calls to a C++ program). It doesn't need to have a GUI.

I searched the web but didn't find something proper.

Someone here who could recommend me a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am searching for a light weight screen recording tool I can use to
>   record automated test runs in the background.

I have used [BB FlashBack Express](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/bbflashbackexpress/compareeditions.aspx) a lot to communicate bugs and issues with offshore teams.

> This is why I would like to use a screen recorder. It should have the
>   following features: - For free if possible, maybe open source -

While it is not open source, the free version works well. Using VLC to playback the flash files seems to work well for us and the file sizes are not too big either (depending on the length of your recording.

> Frame exact screen recording, audio not necessary -

Yes, it does that.

> Windows 7 and XP compatible

Yes.

> Light weight, should not influence the system load too much

Its pretty light weight.

> It should be possible to be started automatically (using
>   command line or by adding some calls to a C++ program).

This comes with the [standard product](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/BBFlashBackExpress/CompareEditions.aspx), and there is an non-free [SDK](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/BBFlashBackSDK.aspx) where you can have full control, as you require, but it is pricy.

Over the years, I have used many screen capture tools. This one seems to fit the bill on a number of fronts.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a dumb idea, but if your computer has multiple video outs (I'm thinking of the shared HDMI on my laptop here), you could record the screen activity on an external piece of hardware.

Good luck, hope this helps.